# What's of meaning of "gets mixed marks" in the following paragraph?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Ideally money provides a reliable store of value, a stable unit of account and an efficient means of payment. Today’s money **gets mixed marks**. Uninsured depositors can suffer if banks fail, bitcoin is not widely accepted and credit cards are expensive. Government e-currencies would score highly, since they are state-guaranteed and use a cheap, central payments hub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The metaphor is based on how teachers give marks to students.

If a student always gets 10/10  then they don't have mixed marks.  If they always get 1/10 then they always get a low mark.

But if the student gets 8/10,  2/10,  5/10, 2/10 10/10, 7/10 ...  The student gets mixed marks, sometimes good and sometimes poor.

The text says "today's money gets mixed marks".  Today's money is good for some things and not good for others.